# Connect to SQL Server and insert values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, database

I'm new to c# and .net so I stacked into inserting data into database.

First I created new project - asp.net web application (v4.6.1). Then I selected web forms template.

My `web.config` file automatically added this lines

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication7-20161108020707.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication7-20161108020707;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

So that is my connection to database.

I started Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. On left side I have object explorer where I see my server (my computer - I use windows authentication). There is folder called databases. I right-clicked on it and selected new database... I created new database called test. Then I expanded test database and right-clicked on tables folder and selected new->table. I added 2 columns. id (int) - not null and name (nchar(255)) - not null. I added id column as is identity. I saved table and name it testing.

Now in Visual Studio I created `Default.aspx` page.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication7._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<asp:TextBox ID="someBox" runat="server" placeholder="enter something"> </asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="clickMe" runat="server" text="click" onclick=clickMe_click />

</asp:Content>
```

And I added into Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication7
{
  public partial class _Default : Page
  {
      protected void clickMe_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        string txtBox = someBox.Text;

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 =
           new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("DefaultConnection");

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT testing (name) VALUES (txtBox)";
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection1.Close();
     }
  }
}
```

I also tried with this code inside click function:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO testing (name) VALUES (@name)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtBox;
cmd.Connection = conn;

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Page refresh and when I refresh table into SQL Server Management Studio and make query:

```
select * from testing;
GO
```

It return 0 rows affected and shows empty table.

What am I doing wrong?

---

edit:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication3-20161105080932.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication3-20161105080932;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

aspnet-WebApplication3-20161105080932 is my database name in server object explorer. Inside db I created table testing.

Here is my cs code:

```
 protected void clickMe_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string txtBox = someBox.Text;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString()))
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO testing (name) VALUES (@name)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtBox;
            int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: @un-lucky, he is already doing it. See posted code.

Comment: string txtBox = someBox.Text;
I get it here into string txtBox so I use txtBox in other part of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a local database. In Visual Studion, go to `View > SQL Server Object Explorer > (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB > aspnet-WebApplication7-20161108020707` to see the contents of your database. No need to start Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication7-20161108020707.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication7-20161108020707;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Use the `using(...)` block for proper disposal when creating a connection to the database.

```
        string txtBox = someBox.Text;
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT testing (name) VALUES (@name)";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtBox;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Sample Output:

[image: Code]

[image: Data]

Comment: Liked the mention of `using(...)` block. But there is no point in opening the connection though you need it way later. Open the connection just before use.

Comment: I get it now. So I have to create testing table into local db? Should I create it into master database or create new db and then table in it?
How my app knows which of internal db do I need ? It's not set anywhere in config and code behind.

Comment: @KondukterCRO since you are using a local database based on your connection string, you should do the necessary steps from there. The initial catalog on your connection refers to the database being used. You don't need to create a new one. You can rename the initial catalog in your connection string into your desired database name. In your case it is currently set to `aspnet-WebApplication7-20161108020707`.

Comment: I updated config file but still nothing. I updated my question with new information.

Comment: I understand. I already got it in string txtBox = someBox.Text; and now I just put it like value. But now when I changed code it doesn't insert nothing into testing table. My cs code and config code are exactly like in updated part of my question. I changed db name into catalog and .mdf. I created table name testing into that db with id and name fields...
Only difference is that I had to add .ToString() into using block.

Comment: @KondukterCRO can you show the definition of your testing table?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testing] (
    [Id]   INT        NOT NULL,
    [name] NCHAR (10) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

Comment: @KondukterCRO try enable seeding on your primary key. It must be expecting a value for `Id` but it is not set to auto-increment which is why your insert fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127676/discussion-between-konduktercro-and-ephraim).

Answer (score 2):

Here is some cleaner code for doing SQL queries (Just my opinion)

```
 using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"]))
 {
     string sql = "INSERT INTO testing (name) VALUES (@name)";
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
     cmd.Parameter.Add(New SqlParameter("@name", txtBox.Text));
     int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     conn.Close();
 }
```

You could also get the number of columns affected by getting the return value of the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery.

I would check into the connection string here is a link 
[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/592675/Get-SQL-Server-Database-Connection-String-Easily-f).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are checking in the wrong place. From your connection string it's clear that you are using a local database as seen below but you are probably checking in some other DB in SSMS

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication7-20161108020707.mdf;
```

Again, your second posted ADO.NET code is correct but you are missing the below line of code

```
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
```

Comment: The default value for the SqlCommand CommandType is text. See [SqlCommand.CommandType Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx)